# Reading and formatting Multilevel, Uneven JSON

Tags: r, tidyverse, jsonlite

I have a JSON like the one shown below

```
{
  "timestamps": [
    "2020-12-17T20:05:00Z",
    "2020-12-17T20:10:00Z",
    "2020-12-17T20:15:00Z",
    "2020-12-17T20:20:00Z",
    "2020-12-17T20:25:00Z",
    "2020-12-17T20:30:00Z"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "values": [
        -20.58975828559592,
        -19.356728999226693,
        -19.808982964173023,
        -19.673928070777993,
        -19.712275037138411,
        -19.48422739982918
      ],
      "name": "Neg Flow",
      "type": "Double"
    },
    {
      "values": [
        2,
        20,
        19,
        20,
        19,
        16
      ],
      "name": "Event Count",
      "type": "Long"
    }
  ],
  "progress": 100.0
}
```

How to convert this to a data frame like the following . Though I was able to loop thorough the individual data items, I am interested in finding if there is a sleek way to do this?

```
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|Time Stamps           | Neg Flow            | Event Count |
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|2020-12-17T20:05:00Z  |-20.58975828559592   | 2           |
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|2020-12-17T20:10:00Z  |-19.356728999226693  | 20          |
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible form which we can copy-paste?

Comment: @RonakShah, the above Json file is the data. Its copy-able !

Comment: When I copy it into R it returns lot of error messages like `Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"` and `Error in "type":"Long" : NA/NaN argument` and so many others. Not sure how to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```
library(jsonlite) # read json
library(dplyr) # maniputate data frame
library(magrittr) # for the use of %<>%

# temp.json is my file using the content you provided
json_data <- read_json("temp.json")

# initial data with timestamp
data <- tibble(`Time Stamps` = unlist(json_data[["timestamps"]]))

# properties process
for (property in json_data[["properties"]]) {
  property_name <- property[["name"]]
  # using dynamic namming for more reference please refer to link at end of post
  data %<>% mutate({{property_name}} := unlist(property[["values"]]))
}
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Time Stamps`        `Neg Flow` `Event Count`
  <chr>                     <dbl>         <int>
1 2020-12-17T20:05:00Z      -20.6             2
2 2020-12-17T20:10:00Z      -19.4            20
3 2020-12-17T20:15:00Z      -19.8            19
4 2020-12-17T20:20:00Z      -19.7            20
5 2020-12-17T20:25:00Z      -19.7            19
6 2020-12-17T20:30:00Z      -19.5            16
```

Learn more about Programming with `dplyr` here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html